# c# datatable "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#

example content in cleaned.txt

> 1.32.48.29 20/Mar/2016:03:40:05 0800 GET /portal/image/find/mobile.png HTTP/1.1 200 3313 http://www.utem.edu.my/portal/ Windows
>
> 1.32.48.29 20/Mar/2016:03:40:05 0800 GET /portal/image/find/qrutem.png HTTP/1.1 200 628 http://www.utem.edu.my/portal/ Windows
>
> 1.32.48.29 20/Mar/2016:03:40:05 0800 GET /portal/image/link/myGov.png HTTP/1.1 200 7483 http://www.utem.edu.my/portal/ Windows

i need to turn into datatable, and heres my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\Cleaned.txt");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("IP Address");   //0
            dt.Columns.Add("Date");         //1
            dt.Columns.Add("Time");         //2 3 4
            dt.Columns.Add("GMT");          //5
            dt.Columns.Add("Method");       //6
            dt.Columns.Add("Resource");     //7
            dt.Columns.Add("Services");     //8
            dt.Columns.Add("Bytes");            //9
            dt.Columns.Add("Destination");      //10
            dt.Columns.Add("Operating System");  //11


            foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                string[] split = line.Split(' ');

                        split = split.Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r)).ToArray();

                        Foo foo = new Foo();

                        foo.IPAddress = split[0];
                        foo.Date = split[1];
                        foo.Time = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", split[2], split[3], split[4]);
                        foo.GMT = split[5];
                        foo.Method = split[6];
                        foo.Resource = split[7];
                        foo.Service = split[8];
                        foo.Bytes = split[9];
                        foo.Destination = split[10];
                        foo.OS = split[11];

                        dt.Rows.Add(foo.IPAddress, foo.Date, foo.Time, foo.GMT, foo.Method, foo.Resource, foo.Service, foo.Bytes, foo.Destination, foo.OS);
                    }

                    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11}", dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6], dr[7], dr[8], dr[9], dr[10], dr[11]));
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

and i got the error on this line

> foo.Destination = split[10];

thanks for your reply

Comment: What value are you getting in the `line` string variable?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, inspect `split` and `line`.

Comment: can you give me a hint on what to do cause i still cant figure it out looking on the similar question.. so sorry. @CodeCaster

Comment: The problem is that the array has fewer elements than you expect it to, so the input string does not contain what you think.

Comment: When i open up the text file, why i have 'System.Data.DataRow' in every row.. do you have any idea?